# How do I add a kdiff3 compare option to Linux Mint Nemo file manager

Tags: linux-mint, file-manager, nemo

I am running the latest version of kdiff3 on Linux Mint 19.1.

When I install kdiff3 on Windows 10, I can then select two files in the file explorer and subsequently right click, the resulting context menu offers a kdiff3 compare option.

Is there a way I can can have a similar behaviour in Nemo file manager on Linux Mint?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

"Nautilus scripts" has been done for that purpose.

See this documentations: (in french, sorry)

- [Nautilus scripts](https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/nautilus_scripts)
- [Advanced usage](https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/nautilus_utilisation_avancee)

*Note that nautilus-actions is no longer supported*

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

1 - Create a ~/.local/share/nemo/scripts/kdiff.bash file

2 - Enter this into the file:

```
#!/bin/bash
readarray -t FILES <<<"$NEMO_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS"
a="${FILES[0]}"
b="${FILES[1]}"
kdiff3 "$a" "$b"
```

3 - Make the file executable

Now, you should have the "kdiff.bash" option in the "scripts" context menu of Nemo.

Answer (score -1):

I do not know a diff tool having this option from the file browser, but will be interesting !

I do not know (until now) kdiff3, I use 'Meld' (entry 5 on the https://www.tecmint.com/best-linux-file-diff-tools-comparison/  )

Here is a good tool to find softwares alternatives :  https://alternativeto.net/software/meld/?platform=linux